# Count consonants in a word randomly found in an array

Tags: php, arrays, strlen

I want to take a random string of the array and should count the consonants of the random string.
Problem is it did not count the letters from array_rand().

Here is what I get at this point:

```
$woerter = [
    "Maus",
    "Automobil",
    "Schifffahrt",
    "Hund",
    "Katze",
    "Ziege",
    "Stanniolpapier",
    "Elefant",
    "Isopropylalkohol",
    "Schwimmbad"
];

$random = array_rand($woerter);

$konsonanten = ["b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
            "B","C","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","M","N","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
$zaehler = 0;
if (in_array($woerter[$random], $konsonanten)) {
    $zaehler++;
}

echo "Das Wort \"$woerter[$random]\" enthält $zaehler Zeichen, die keine Vokale sind.";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing whether the whole word is in the array of consonants, not counting each character. You need to loop over the characters.

```
$word = $woerter[$random];
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++) {
    if (in_array($word[$i], $konsonanten)) {
        $zaehler++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't mean to offend, but you weren't thinking clearly about what you wanted to do. How could one `if` statement without a loop count anything?

Answer (score 1):

Writing out a full array of whitelisted consonants seems more tedious that I'd prefer to code.  Making looped calls of `in_array()` on each character doesn't feel clever/efficient to me either.

Consider merely stripping out all vowels, then counting what is left.  Mind you, if your words might have multibyte/accented characters, you'll need to accommodate that possibility too.  `mb_strlen()` might be necessary as well (instead of `strlen()`).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9bDMJ))

```
foreach ($woerter as $word) {
    echo "Consonants found in $word: " . strlen(str_ireplace(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'], '', $word)) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Consonants found in Maus: 2
Consonants found in Automobil: 4
Consonants found in Schifffahrt: 9
Consonants found in Hund: 3
Consonants found in Katze: 3
Consonants found in Ziege: 2
Consonants found in Stanniolpapier: 8
Consonants found in Elefant: 4
Consonants found in Isopropylalkohol: 10
Consonants found in Schwimmbad: 8
```